# Indexing an Indefinite series with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series, glob

As part of a larger project, I am trying to get pandas to index file names that may vary in their length so that I can refer to the file names later. Is there a way to index series without specifying a set number of indexes?

Just for clarification, I would like to avoid doing:

```
ser = pd.Series(filename, index = ['a', 'b', ..., 'n'])
```

for each file, but rather have pandas recognize the number of entries in each name and index them based on the varying length.

**Update:** After trying to troubleshoot a bit, this is what I have found. Type seems to be correct, becasue `type(ser)` gives `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. The output I am getting is `0    g17210b03_20180906_104228_AM_AverageSpectrum.csv dtype: object`. Looking at values and index, I find the following results: `ser.values` gives `['g17210b01_20180906_104202_AM_AverageSpectrum.csv']`, which seems right, however, `ser.values` gives `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1)`, which seems incorrect, since the series contains more than just a single character (which I assume is being read as the '0' in the output).

Comment: What is `filename`; an array of data, just a string, a list of filenames??

Comment: The files themselves are arrays of data, but I am interested in the actual string of the filename. So it is a list of filenames.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the question then. Pandas will always create an index for you. Given your example, it's not clear why you need it to be alphabetical, instead of the default integer range index it will create.

Comment: I guess I am just running into issues specifying the indexing, then, because when I index the filenames and try to reference them afterward, the entire filename is all that is shown. So when I have `ser = pd.Series(filename)` then try to reference it later `print(ser[:5])` for example, the whole filename still is printed.